# Is there an easy way to create academic looking tables in LaTeX from R econometric tests and models

Tags: econometrics, autoregressive

I have tried using the obvious choice - the Stargazer package in R. But, as far as I know, Stargazer does not support packages like 'vars' (for VAR and VECM models, the Johansen procedure, etc...) and 'urca' (for unit root tests). It's a shame, because linear models are represented very nicely in tables with Stargazer.
What do you use to simplify the table creation process?

Comment: Hi: you should ask on the R-list or R on stackexchange. you'll most likely get lots of replies. I tend to think that you would make them in markdown ( or latex ) but, given the # of packages, there might be one out there that does it for you. I don't know.